# How to use an outer join on 3 tables.

Tags: sql, oracle

In my database, I have to list the name, displacement, and number of guns for all ships that fought in the battle of Guadalcanal. For this I need to use 3 tables. The name comes from the Ships table, the number of guns and the displacement comes from the Classes table and the battle comes from the battles table.

```
Create Table Classes (
    class Varchar(40),
    type Char (2),
    country Varchar(15),
    numGuns Int,
    bore Int,
    displacement Int
);
Create Table Ships (
    name Varchar(40),
    class Varchar(40),
    launched Int
);
Create Table Battles(
    name Varchar(40),
    date_fought Date
);
```

Here's a query that I've tried to use:

```
Select Ships.name, displacement, numGuns
From (Classes Full Outer Join Ships ON Classes.class = Ships.class), Battles
Where Battles.name = 'Guadalcanal';
```

Now this doesn't work mainly because I don't think I'm using outer joins correctly. The problem is I don't know how to use outer joins for 3 tables.

Comment: There's no relationship between BATTLES and the other two tables. So what are you expecting to happen? Also, you don't select any columns from that table. So how would you know it was doing anything?

Comment: Just add another outer join for the third table after the first.  A side note, you should never have commas in the `from` clause.  What you're creating in your query is a `full join` between `Classes` and `Ships` and a `cross join` to `Battles`.

Answer (score 2):

First identify where your primary sources of information are.  Here you are looking for a battle and the associated ships and their classes.  OUTER JOIN means that it will return one side even if there is no match on the other side.  In this case if you start with battles you only want ships that match so:

```
select     b.name 
from       Battles b 
inner join Ships   s on b.name = s.battle_name
```

I don't think you have anything to link ships to battles yet.  My guess is that you are missing an XREF table matching ships to battles.

Battle_Ships

```
+++++++++++++++
battle  | ship
+++++++++++++++
battle1 | ship1
battle1 | ship2
battle1 | ship3
battle2 | ship3
battle2 | ship4
```

With this you could get the battles and ships like so:

```
select          b.name, s.name 
from            Battles      b 
left outer join Battle_Ships bs on b.name = bs.battle 
left outer join Ships        s  on bs.ship = s.name
```

Then you'll want to get the class of the ship so you can get displacement but I'm guessing that may not exist, so you'll want to outer join that

```
select          s.name, c.numGuns, c.displacement 
from            Ships   s 
left outer join Classes c on s.class = c.class
```

All together you'll have something like:

```
select          b.name, s.name, c.numGuns, c.displacement 
from            Battles      b 
left outer join Battle_Ships bs on b.name = bs.battle 
left outer join Ships        s  on bs.ship = s.name 
left outer join Classes      c  on s.class = c.class 
where           b.name = 'Guadalcanal'
```

Again, left outer join means match left side and return right side if it exists.  Here we start at Battle, then match Battle_Ships if there are any, which match Ships if there are any, then Classes.  You almost never want to use a full outer join unless you also wanted to show what ships were never in a battle as well (because then it would allow for the left hand side to be empty as well).

Comment: Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

What is the key shared by battles and Classes/ships? Once you have that, the following should work. This edits assumes Ships is what shares a key with Battle.

```
SELECT Ships.name, displacement, numGuns
FROM Ships 
FULL JOIN Classes ON Classes.class = Ships.class,
FULL JOIN Battles ON Battles.ThatKey = Ships.SameKey
WHERE Battles.name = 'Guadalcanal';
```

Comment: Using `Battles` in the `WHERE` clause invalidates the `OUTER JOIN`.  This *must* be in the `ON` clause (which you are also missing from the second `FULL JOIN`).

Answer (score 0):

First off, you want to have a primary key in each table so that you can relate the tables to each other accurately.  If class is unique in the classes table and every Ship record has a class that is listed in the Classes table, then that would work as a key in the Classes table.  Unless every ship name, regardless of class, is unique, then you would need a primary key in that table as well.  A primary key is needed on Battles as well.
  The Battles and Ships tables will most likely have a many to many relationship with each other.  A ship can be in more than one battle, and a battle can have more than one ship.  Another table is needed to link these 2 tables together.  Perhaps (using only the column names you have here) the table could be Battles_Ships_Rel:

```
Create Table Battles_Ships_Rel (
    battles_ships_rel_id Int,
    battle_name Varchar(40),
    ship_name Varchar(40)
);
```

This wouldn't be ideal because the battle_name and ship_name both refer to columns that have the same name but different meaning in 2 different tables.  Also, a full outer join would get records you did not want because it would pull records from all 3 tables whether they had matches or not.  If you want only ships from the Battle of Guadalcanal, then you want an inner join (unless no ships fought in that battle, but I think that is not the case).  We can leave Classes outer joined to ships since outer join is what you requested, but it should be a left outer join.  The below query would work:

```
SELECT Ships.name, Classes.displacement, Classes.numGuns
FROM Ships
INNER JOIN Battles_Ships_Rel
  ON Ships.name = Battles_Ships_Rel.ship_name
LEFT INNER JOIN Classes
--all ships, but only classes that have a record for Ships.class
  ON Ships.class = Classes.class 
WHERE Battles_Ships_Rel.battle_name = 'Guadalcanal';
```

The Battles table is not needed since we have the battle name in Battles_Ships_Rel in this example.